# Updating UILabel and Deleteing row from UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UITableview`  and I populate the rows with data from an api.

I have made code to update the label of the item in the cell row if more than on of the same item is added to the tableview. If a new item is added it populates a new cell row with the information.

I am trying now to use the `UITableview`  editing method to delete rows from the `UITableview`.

I have no problem with deleting rows but My problem is that how can I delete the quantity if the item in the cell row is more than 1 and if the quantuty is only one delete the cell row.

I am getting a strange bug when trying to do this.

My code minuses to many times, please see my code and screenshots.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
NSLog(@"Order ID: %ld", (long)self.orderId);

if ([self.prevVC isKindOfClass:[MyOrdersViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"from my orders view");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}else {

    NSLog(@"from my deli item view %@", self.deli.deliId);
    NSLog(@"from my menu item view %ld", (long)self.menuItem.menuItemId);
    NSLog(@"menu item array %@", self.menuItem);

    self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: self.menuItem.menuItemId]  forKey: @"id"];
    [self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary setObject: self.menuItem.menuItemDescription  forKey: @"description"];
    [self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary setObject: self.menuItem.menuItemImageURL  forKey: @"imageUrlString"];
    [self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary setObject: self.menuItem.menuItemPrice  forKey: @"price"];
    [self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary setObject: self.menuItem.menuItemCurrency  forKey: @"currency"];

    NSArray *arr = [self.newestViewOrderSummaryArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger: self.menuItem.menuItemId]]];
    NSLog(@"arr arr arr %@", arr);
    if (arr && arr.count == 1) {
        NSMutableDictionary* foundMenuItem = (NSMutableDictionary*) [arr objectAtIndex: 0];
        self.quantity = [[foundMenuItem objectForKey: @"quantity"] intValue];
        self.quantity++;
        [foundMenuItem setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", self.quantity] forKey: @"quantity"];
        [self.newestViewOrderSummaryArray removeObject: foundMenuItem];
        self.viewOrderSummaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.newestViewOrderSummaryArray];
        [self.viewOrderSummaryArray addObject: foundMenuItem];
    }
    else {
        [self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary setObject: @"1"  forKey: @"quantity"];
        [self.viewOrderSummaryArray addObject: self.viewOrderSummaryDictionary];
        [self.viewOrderSummaryArray addObjectsFromArray: self.newestViewOrderSummaryArray];
    }

   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self showBackButton];
self.navBarBackLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(65, 5, 200, 30)];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"View Order Summary", nil);
self.navBarBackLabel.textColor = [UIColor appRedColor];
self.navBarBackLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeWP" size:15];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.navBarBackLabel];

self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

self.viewOrderSummaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self setupTableViewHeader];

}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    return 30.0f;
    }

- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor appOrderScreenHeaderBackgroundColor];

self.headerViewWhite = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 30.0f)];
self.headerViewWhite.backgroundColor = [UIColor appYellowColor];

[self.headerViewWhite addSubview:self.deliNameLabel];

[self.headerView addSubview:self.headerViewWhite];

return self.headerView;
}

- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 115;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.viewOrderSummaryArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

ViewOrderSummaryCell *cell = (ViewOrderSummaryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewOrderSummaryCell"];

cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
//self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
//cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

NSDictionary* currentItem = [self.viewOrderSummaryArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

cell.productNameLabel.text = [currentItem objectForKey: @"description"];
cell.productPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@ x %@",[currentItem objectForKey: @"currency"],[currentItem objectForKey: @"price"], [currentItem objectForKey: @"quantity"]]; // TODO: Must implement this later
[cell.productImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[currentItem objectForKey: @"imageUrlString"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appPlaceholderImage"]];

CALayer * l = [cell.productImageView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];

float sumq = 0;
NSArray *array = [self.viewOrderSummaryArray valueForKey:@"price"];
for (NSNumber *num in array)
{


    sumq += [num floatValue];
}

float currentPrice = [[currentItem objectForKey: @"price"] floatValue];
float quantity = [[currentItem objectForKey: @"quantity"] intValue];
sumPrice += (currentPrice * quantity);

return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.

return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //add code here for when you hit delete

    NSLog(@"Selected row of section >> %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Selected row is %@", [self.viewOrderSummaryArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] );

    NSMutableDictionary* currentItem = [self.viewOrderSummaryArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    if ([[currentItem objectForKey: @"quantity"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [self.viewOrderSummaryArray removeObject:[self.viewOrderSummaryArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        NSLog(@"Quantity label");
    }

    else {
        self.quantity--;
        [currentItem setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", self.quantity] forKey: @"quantity"];
        [self.newestViewOrderSummaryArray removeObject: currentItem];
        self.viewOrderSummaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.newestViewOrderSummaryArray];
        [self.viewOrderSummaryArray addObject: currentItem];
        NSLog(@"Many label");
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return NO;
}
```